# Making "Fill in the Blank" in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am quite new to react and I am trying to make a fill in the blank app with react. Basically, I have a passage with a word list. I want to replace all occurrences each word with a blank so that the user can type in the answer. After that, if the user clicks the submit button, it displays the result saying how many they got right.

After doing some research, I found [reactStringReplace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-string-replace) package which can safely replace strings with react components. This is how I generate the blanks in the passage:

```
getFillInTheBlank() {
    let passage = this.passage;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.wordList.length; i++) {
        let regexp = new RegExp("\\b(" + this.wordList[i] + ")\\b", "gi");
        passage = reactStringReplace(passage, regexp, (match, i) => (
            <input type="text"></input>
        ));
    }
    return <div>passage</div>
}
```

However, I can't figure out a way to check each input text with respective words to calculate the score when the submit button is clicked. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I made it using Mobx, but it can be easily edited to work without this library.

This is the model, which contains the word to guess and the main events callbacks

word-guess.tsx

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";
export class WordGuess {

private wordToGuess: string;

// Needed to select the next empty char when the component gain focus
private nextEmptyCharIndex = 0;

guessedChars: string[];
focusedCharIndex = -1;

constructor(wordToGuess: string) {
    this.wordToGuess = wordToGuess;

    // In "guessedChars" all chars except white spaces are replaced with empty strings
    this.guessedChars = wordToGuess.split('').map(char => char === ' ' ? char : '');
    makeAutoObservable(this);
}

onCharInput = (input: string) => {
    this.guessedChars[this.focusedCharIndex] = input;
    this.focusedCharIndex += 1;

    if(this.nextEmptyCharIndex < this.focusedCharIndex){
        this.nextEmptyCharIndex = this.focusedCharIndex;
    }
};

onFocus = () => this.focusedCharIndex = 
    this.nextEmptyCharIndex >= this.wordToGuess.length ? 0 : this.nextEmptyCharIndex;
onFocusLost = () => this.focusedCharIndex = -1;
}
```

Input Component

guess-input.tsx

```
interface GuessInputProps {
    wordGuess: WordGuess;
}
export const GuessInput = observer((props: GuessInputProps) => {

const { guessedChars, focusedCharIndex, onCharInput, onFocus, onFocusLost } = 
    props.wordGuess;

const containerRef = useRef(null);

const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    const ref: any = containerRef?.current;
    ref?.focus();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {

    const onKeyDown = (params: KeyboardEvent) => {
        const key = params.key;
        if (focusedCharIndex >= 0 && key.length === 1 && key.match(/[A-zÀ-ú]/)) {
            onCharInput(params.key);

            // Clear focus when last character is inserted
            if(focusedCharIndex === guessedChars.length - 1) {
                const ref: any = containerRef?.current;
                ref?.blur();
            }
        }
    };

    document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
    };
}, [focusedCharIndex, guessedChars]);

return <div className='guess-input' 
    onClick={onClick} ref={containerRef} 
    onFocus={onFocus} onBlur={onFocusLost} tabIndex={-1}>
        {guessedChars.map((char, index) => 
          <CharToGuess key={index} value={char} focused={index === focusedCharIndex} />)
        }
</div>;
});
```

Component representing each one of the characters

char-to-guess.tsx

```
import './guess-input.scss';
interface CharToGuessProps {
    value: string;
    focused: boolean;
}
export const CharToGuess = (props: CharToGuessProps) => {
    const { focused, value } = props;

    return <span className={`char-to-guess ${focused ? ' focused-char' : ''}`}>
        {value || '_'} 
    </span>;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to create blank strings.

Take a look at this code and see if you understand it.

```
var answer = document.getElementById('guess-input').name;

var hint = document.getElementById('guess-input').value;

function guessAnswer() {
  $("button.guess-submit").click(function(event) {

    var guess = $('#guess-input').val();
    guess = guess.toLowerCase();

    if ( guess == answer) {
      $('#correct').show();
      $('#wrong').hide();
    } else {
      $('#wrong').show().fadeOut(1000);
      $('#guess-input').val(hint);
    }

  });

}

function enterSubmit() {
   $("#guess-input").keyup(function(event){
      if(event.keyCode == 13){
          $("#guess-submit").click();
      }
   });

  guessAnswer();
}

enterSubmit();

if ( $('#correct').css('display') == 'block') {
    alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: generally you should  add comment and explanation about your answer

Comment: He want's a solution in react and not in Jquery.

Comment: Oh even better, useState.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to send a request to server with the questions and answers and return the results. If you save the points or the answers in the frontend, is possible that the game will be altered.